# Window.Location?

Tags: wpf, window, location

Is there a way to manually set a WPF Window's location like in [Windows-Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159414.aspx)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Left](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.left.aspx) and [Top](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.top.aspx) Properties.